# SharePoint server, can it be downloaded as standalone website?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, public-website

I have a SharePoint server, on site (Ireland), and its working fine.
we also have an office in Jordan, that connects to our domain via a 2nd Firewall.

so they are in a different IP range etc.
they want to access our SharePoint server, and I have got it working by editing the host file on one of their machines. and entering credentials when prompted.

but its very slow. 
2-3 minutes to load a page. so unusable really.  (and the boss man won't is happy)

any suggestions on how to improve this so that it's usable for the offsite users.
we have an office in the UK also, they connect via VPN and that works fine, Sharepoint works well there.

is it possible to download SharePoint as a website, and just dump it on one of their servers ?

any suggestions appreciated. 
(I'm not great on networking, so any suggestions welcome)

Traceroute info is 97MS per hop

Comment: Do you have trust between domains?

Comment: Not within AD, thier site is not a subsite off ours, but they connect in via firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

You can think about moving the SharePoint environment into a cloud hosting provider or you can choose SharePoint Online.

If you still want to retain on-premise setup then you can have geographical replication of SharePoint farms and use 3rd party tool for synchronization or use SQL server mirroring.

Talking about download site.. You should setup a similar Farm in you other office location, then backup restore content databases. Here you can use SQL mirroring to keep the databases in different offices in sync.